# How many elements of order 3 do distinct Sylow 3-subgroups "use up" in a group G

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

I am working on a question stated as such:

> Let $|G| = 12$. Show that $G$ either has a normal Sylow 2-subgroup, or a normal Sylow
> 3-subgroup; and so $G$ is not simple.

I am failing to understand a statement from the solution:

> each distinct Sylow 3-subgroup will use up two elements of order 3 from the group.

Wouldn't a Sylow 3-subgroup be of the form $\{e, a, a^2\}$, thus containing one element of order 3 from the group? (Since the order of the Sylow 3-subgroup is $3$, which is prime, thus the subgroup is cyclic.)

Comment: Are not both $a$ and its square of order three?

Comment: $a$ and $a^2$ both have order three. And there cannot be another subgroup containing $a^2$ but not containing $a$. That's because $(a^2)^2=a^4=a^3a=a$ comes together with $a^2$.

Comment: I see, a silly mistake from me. Thank you for the quick clarification